# Получить кол-во шеров страницы в ВК?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

На LP для голосования для каждого видео используется социальные сети. Проблема в том что периодические скачет число сделанных шеров через ВК. С утра показывает что видео 89 голосов сделанных через ВК, а через пару часов становится 1 или какое ещё друге число.
Кол-во шеров узнаю так:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/456239060';
    preg_match('/[\d]+/',$url, $idx);
      $data = file_get_contents('https://vk.com/share.php?act=count&index='.$idx[0].'&url='.$url);
     if(preg_match('/VK\.Share\.count\([0-9]+, ([0-9]+)\)\;/is', $data, $match)) {
          $data = intval($match[1]);
          return $data;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
```

Запрос о кол-во шеров происходит каждый раз когда страница загружается.

Видео встраиваться из альбома в вк, голоса собираются не только из вк но и из других соц сетей. Получается что репоститься сайта

Answer (score 0):

Получение количества репостов страницы:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://example.com';
$q = file_get_contents('http://vk.com/share.php?act=count&url='.$url);
$count = substr($q, 18, -2);
echo $count;
?>
```